# cordova InAppBrowser knockout.js click event

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, knockout.js, click

I have messaging hybrid app like phonegap using knockout.js where I want to make any message having url and/or a number to become link and open in browser/dial pad. I added this click event which returns true value but still it does not automatically open up in browser when clicked if url or number is present in the text message.

```
<span data-bind="text: content,  click: function() { return true;}"></span>
```

I tried something like this as well -

```
    <span data-bind="text: content, click: $parent.openLink.bind($data, content)"></span>
   self.openLink = function(customParam, data, event) {

 if (customParam.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig))
        {   cordova.InAppBrowser.open(customParam, '_blank', 'location=yes'); }
```

This way I can open any link if its present in the message , but this way it makes whole message hyperlinked. So an issue if message has more than 1 url and a number in the same message.

Need a approach where I can simply make a format detection (url or number) and make it a link.
P.s  I also added this

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="url=yes"> which also does not work.
```